# How to retain the dropdown value inside gridview after footer button click

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview, onchange

[image]I have a Dropdown1 outside gridview contains three options Select,A,B.

Inside gridview two dropdowns Dropdown2,Dropdown3  in which Dropdown2 contains three options say Select,C,D.

Based on Dropdown1 & Dropdown2, I am populating Dropdown3 using onchange event in javascript in Dropdown2.

everything working fine for First row but when I add new row, Dropdown3 value vanishes to default "Select"

[image]

**Javascript function**

```
function DataformatFetch(Selection) {
                var status = Selection.options[Selection.selectedIndex].value;
                var row = Selection.parentNode.parentNode;
                var rowIndex = row.rowIndex - 1;

                if (document.getElementById("<%=DropDown1.ClientID%>").value == "A") {
                    var Dataformatlist = row.cells[7].getElementsByTagName('SELECT')[0];                    
                    switch (status) {
                        case "Select":
                            Dataformatlist.options.length = 0;
                            Dataformatlist.options[0] = new Option("Select","Select");
                            break;
                        case "C":
                            Dataformatlist.options.length = 0;
                            Dataformatlist.options[0] = new Option("Select","Select");
                            Dataformatlist.options[1] = new Option("1","1");
                            Dataformatlist.options[2] = new Option("2","2");
                            Dataformatlist.options[3] = new Option("3","3");
                            break;
                        case "D":
                            Dataformatlist.options.length = 0;
                            Dataformatlist.options[0] = new Option("Select","Select");
                            Dataformatlist.options[1] = new Option("11","11");
                            Dataformatlist.options[2] = new Option("22","22");
                            Dataformatlist.options[3] = new Option("33","33");                           
                            break;
                    }
                }

                else if (document.getElementById("<%=DropDown1.ClientID%>").value == "B") {
                    var Dataformatlist = row.cells[7].getElementsByTagName('SELECT')[0];
                    switch (status) {
                        case "Select":
                            Dataformatlist.options.length = 0;
                            Dataformatlist.options[0] = new Option("Select");
                            break;
                        case "C":
                            Dataformatlist.options.length = 0;
                            Dataformatlist.options[0] = new Option("Select","Select");
                            Dataformatlist.options[1] = new Option("111","111");
                            Dataformatlist.options[2] = new Option("222","222");
                            Dataformatlist.options[3] = new Option("333","333");
                            break;
                        case "D":
                            Dataformatlist.options.length = 0;
                            Dataformatlist.options[0] = new Option("Select","Select");
                            Dataformatlist.options[1] = new Option("1111","1111");
                            Dataformatlist.options[2] = new Option("2222","2222");
                            Dataformatlist.options[3] = new Option("3333","3333");
                            break;
                    }
                }                 
            }
```

ASPX code

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderText="Object Type">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                   <asp:DropDownList ID="Dropdownlist2" runat="server" OnChange="DataformatFetch(this);">
                                        <asp:ListItem Value="Select">Select</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem Value="C">C</asp:ListItem>
                                        <asp:ListItem Value="D">D</asp:ListItem>
                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
```

C# code

```
 private void AddNewRowToGrid()
        {
            try
            {
                if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
                {
                    System.Data.DataTable dtCurrentTable = (System.Data.DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
                    DataRow drCurrentRow = null;

                    if (dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        drCurrentRow = dtCurrentTable.NewRow();
                        //drCurrentRow["REQUESTNO"] = dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count + 1;

                        dtCurrentTable.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow);
                        ViewState["CurrentTable"] = dtCurrentTable;

                        for (int i = 0; i < dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
                        {
                            TextBox box2 = (TextBox)DataExchangeGridView.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("PTNTextBox");
                            TextBox box3 = (TextBox)DataExchangeGridView.Rows[i].Cells[1].FindControl("PTDTextBox");
                            TextBox box4 = (TextBox)DataExchangeGridView.Rows[i].Cells[2].FindControl("PTRTextBox");
                            DropDownList box5 = (DropDownList)DataExchangeGridView.Rows[i].Cells[3].FindControl("PIPRDropdownlist");
                            DropDownList box6 = (DropDownList)DataExchangeGridView.Rows[i].Cells[4].FindControl("SupplierNameDroplist");
                            DropDownList box7 = (DropDownList)DataExchangeGridView.Rows[i].Cells[5].FindControl("ObjectTypeDropdownlist");
                            DropDownList box8 = (DropDownList)DataExchangeGridView.Rows[i].Cells[6].FindControl("DataformatDropdownlist");

                            dtCurrentTable.Rows[i]["PARTNUMBER"] = box2.Text;
                            dtCurrentTable.Rows[i]["PARTDESCRIPTION"] = box3.Text;
                            dtCurrentTable.Rows[i]["PARTREVISION"] = box4.Text;
                            dtCurrentTable.Rows[i]["PARTIPR"] = box5.Text;
                            dtCurrentTable.Rows[i]["SUPPLIERNAME"] = box6.Text;
                            dtCurrentTable.Rows[i]["OBJECTTYPE"] = box7.Text;
                            dtCurrentTable.Rows[i]["DATAFORMAT"] = box8.Text;
                        }

                        DataExchangeGridView.DataSource = dtCurrentTable;
                        DataExchangeGridView.DataBind();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Response.Write("ViewState is null");
                }
                SetPreviousData();
            }
            catch (Exception rt)
            {
                rt.ToString();
            }
        }       

        private void SetPreviousData()
        {
            try
            {
                int rowIndex = 0;
                if (this.DataExTypeDropDownList.SelectedItem.Value == "Import")
                {
                    if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
                    {
                        System.Data.DataTable dt = (System.Data.DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
                        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                        {
                            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                            {
                                System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox box2 = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox)DataExchangeGridView.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0].FindControl("PTNTextBox");
                                System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox box3 = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox)DataExchangeGridView.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("PTDTextBox");
                                System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox box4 = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox)DataExchangeGridView.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("PTRTextBox");
                                box2.Enabled = box3.Enabled = box4.Enabled = false;
                                box2.Text = string.Empty;
                                box3.Text = string.Empty;
                                box4.Text = string.Empty;
                                System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList box5 = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList)DataExchangeGridView.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("PIPRDropdownlist");
                                System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList box6 = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList)DataExchangeGridView.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[4].FindControl("SupplierNameDroplist");
                                System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList box7 = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList)DataExchangeGridView.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[5].FindControl("ObjectTypeDropdownlist");
                                System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList box8 = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList)DataExchangeGridView.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[6].FindControl("DataformatDropdownlist");

                                //FillDropDownList(box8);

                                if (i < dt.Rows.Count - 1)
                                {
                                    box2.Text = dt.Rows[i]["PARTNUMBER"].ToString();
                                    box3.Text = dt.Rows[i]["PARTDESCRIPTION"].ToString();
                                    box4.Text = dt.Rows[i]["PARTREVISION"].ToString();
                                    box5.Text = dt.Rows[i]["PARTIPR"].ToString();
                                    box6.Text = dt.Rows[i]["SUPPLIERNAME"].ToString();
                                    box7.Text = dt.Rows[i]["OBJECTTYPE"].ToString();
                                    //box8.Text = dt.Rows[i]["DATAFORMAT"].ToString();
                                    string XE = box8.Items.FindByText(dt.Rows[i]["DATAFORMAT"].ToString()).Value;
                                    box8.Text = XE;
                                }
                                rowIndex++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if (this.DataExTypeDropDownList.SelectedItem.Value == "Export")
                {
                    if (ViewState["CurrentTable"] != null)
                    {
                        System.Data.DataTable dt = (System.Data.DataTable)ViewState["CurrentTable"];
                        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                        {
                            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                            {
                                System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox box2 = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox)DataExchangeGridView.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[0].FindControl("PTNTextBox");
                                System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox box3 = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox)DataExchangeGridView.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[1].FindControl("PTDTextBox");
                                System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox box4 = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox)DataExchangeGridView.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("PTRTextBox");
                                System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList box5 = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList)DataExchangeGridView.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[3].FindControl("PIPRDropdownlist");
                                System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList box6 = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList)DataExchangeGridView.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[4].FindControl("SupplierNameDroplist");
                                System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList box7 = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList)DataExchangeGridView.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[5].FindControl("ObjectTypeDropdownlist");
                                System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList box8 = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList)DataExchangeGridView.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[6].FindControl("DataformatDropdownlist");

                                if (i < dt.Rows.Count - 1)
                                {
                                    box2.Text = dt.Rows[i]["PARTNUMBER"].ToString();
                                    box3.Text = dt.Rows[i]["PARTDESCRIPTION"].ToString();
                                    box4.Text = dt.Rows[i]["PARTREVISION"].ToString();
                                    box5.Text = dt.Rows[i]["PARTIPR"].ToString();
                                    box6.Text = dt.Rows[i]["SUPPLIERNAME"].ToString();
                                    box7.Text = dt.Rows[i]["OBJECTTYPE"].ToString();
                                    box8.Text = dt.Rows[i]["DATAFORMAT"].ToString();
                                }

                                rowIndex++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception er)
            {
                er.ToString();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Maybe, post back occurs on add row. If so, then you may need to preserve the value using view state or some other suitable method and set it back to ddl

Comment: @Chidambaram Can you explain a bit more with sample code please.

Answer (score 0):

To start with, the data format is not getting passed back due it being generated client side, so we can add a hidden field to save that value.

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="selectedValue" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("Dataformat") %>' />
```

How we populate that field is adding OnChange to the data format dropdown.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="Dropdownlist7" runat="server" OnChange="DataformatSelect(this);">

function DataformatSelect(Selection) {
    var selectedValue = Selection.options[Selection.selectedIndex].value;
    Selection.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('INPUT')[0].value = selectedValue;
}
```

On the server side, we must return all the data on postback (and on initial load).

```
private DataTable GetEmptyTable()
{
    var table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.Add("ObjectType", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("Dataformat", typeof(string));
    return table;
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        var table = GetEmptyTable();
        table.Rows.Add("Select", "Select");
        GridView1.DataSource = table;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}

protected void btnAddRow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var table = GetEmptyTable();
    DataRow dr;

    foreach (GridViewRow gvr in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        dr = table.NewRow();
        DropDownList ddlObjectType = gvr.FindControl("Dropdownlist2") as DropDownList;
        HiddenField hdnDataFormat = gvr.FindControl("selectedValue") as HiddenField;

        dr[0] = ddlObjectType.SelectedValue;
        dr[1] = hdnDataFormat.Value;

        table.Rows.Add(dr);
    }

    table.Rows.Add("Select", "Select");

    GridView1.DataSource = table;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Ensure the Object Type is getting populated with the Bind.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="Dropdownlist2" runat="server" OnChange="DataformatFetch(this);" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("ObjectType") %>'>
```

Finally, on page load, we need to sync up the client side generated drop down lists.

```
<body onload="pageLoad();">

function pageLoad() {
    [].forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName('tr'), function (row, index) {
        if (index == 0) {
            return;
        }

        DataformatFetch(row.cells[0].getElementsByTagName('select')[0]);

        var selectedValue = row.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].value;
        row.cells[1].getElementsByTagName('select')[0].value = selectedValue;
    });
}
```

Hopefully that fills in any missing gaps to what you already have.

Thanks a lot to [add new row in gridview after binding C#, ASP.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19485909/add-new-row-in-gridview-after-binding-c-asp-net)

Comment: I modifed your coding according to my requirement but not getting the desired result. Can you check my C# code and tell me where i going wrong. I have uploaded my whole form for your reference.

Comment: Getting JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'options' of undefined or null reference for this line " var status = Selection.options[Selection.selectedIndex].value;"

Comment: I think I have a different number of columns than you, could you please update this line "DataformatFetch(row.cells[0]..." to "DataformatFetch(row.cells[6]..."?

Comment: I am getting the above error after giving cell value to 6 only.

Comment: and getting JavaScript runtime error: 'pageload' is undefined also